# Why would my code show an error on my select position?

Tags: mysql

select route_name,routeid,route_backup from route where convert(int,route_act_duration)>convert(int,route_exp_duration)

"select" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: '(', WITH

Comment: Is there a semicolon on the preceding line?

Comment: Even if I put a semicolon it still shows an error

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471882/mysql-workbench-reports-is-not-valid-at-this-position-for-this-server-version